# Simple way to assign the matrix

Tags: r

Is there another way  to assign the matrix?

```
> x<-matrix(NA,nrow=3,ncol=4)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

One way is `x[2:10]<-2:10`  `t(x)` .

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
[4,]   10   NA   NA
```

i am  asking in general how to assign values to  part  of matrices (the part of matrices are not matrices,it is only part of it).

Comment: `matrix(c(NA, 2:10, NA, NA), nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you just want this particular matrix, or are you asking in general how to assign values to subsets of matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case, where the matrix elements you wish to assign may not even be neighbors, you should use both indices with the `[<-` tools.  E.g. (for a larger matrix than your example)

```
x[1:3,4]<-8:10
```

or

```
x[5,c(3,7,11)]<- c(5,3,1)
```

and so on.  If there's a pattern to the replacement locations, you can write loops over the indices of interest.